# What kind of input Jack can work on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) audio input port?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I was planning to buy a new mic for my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012), but I tried connecting an old mic and nothing happened. The old mic is not broken, because I tested it on another PC and it worked.

I just want to know if I can connect the mic that I was planning to buy.

I was thinking of this microphone: [http://www.amazon.com/Tonor-TN12326-Professional-Condenser-Microphone/dp/B00PZMP3Z0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PZMP3Z0)

[image]

Comment: That microphone uses a 3.5mm audio jack, which your Mac has. It should fit.

Answer (score 2):

Any line-level input should work with the [15-inch Mid 2012 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP694?locale=en_US) (the MBPr is slightly different.) Simply insert it into the audio in port on your MacBook Pro using a 3.5mm jack. [image]

[Line level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) simply refers to relatively amplified analog signal. Not all microphones provide this: if necessary, you may need to use an amplifier.

I'm not sure why the microphone you already have didn't work: there's nothing that should be preventing it. If you can provide more info, we might be able to help.

Comment: The mic probably is providing a mic level input,

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, as a condenser microphone yours needs power which can not be supplied through this input.

The link you've provided explicitly says:

> "This microphone does not support Mac devices"